# Places Autocomplete in Google Forms App Script

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-places-api, google-forms

I am new to Google Forms and Google App Script. I am trying to create a form dynamically that takes a users address. I would like to incorporate Google's Places Autocomplete style input for the user address field but I cannot find any example or resource.

Help appreciated!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in forms. You can only use the native controls and at this point is not possible to run code inside the form.

Answer (score 1):

for a text box inside an Apps Script web app:

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('HTML')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

HTML.html

```
<!doctype html>

<div>
  <input id="searchTextField" type="text"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<script>
  var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {types:['geocode']});

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() { 
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();});
</script>
```

Comment: this script doesn't work with Google forms, it works if you have an HTML web page and want to use location API.